# Why is my png image exporting with grey border around icon?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, png

The icon looks fine in Indesign but when I export it as a PDF, there is this ugly grey fuzz around some parts of the icon's border.

I initially downloaded the image as a png, edited it in Photoshop to change the colour from white to red and then saved it again as a png to place into InDesign. I didn't see any grey fuzz/pixels initially when editing it in Photoshop.

[image: After in PDF]

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

> I initially downloaded the image as a png, edited it in Photoshop to change the colour from white to red and then saved it again as a png to place into InDesign. I didn't see any grey fuzz/pixels initially when editing it in Photoshop.

*How* you changed color may make all the difference in the world. In addition to the original background of the image.

For the sake of clarity, I'll assume the original was a white clipboard icon on a transparent background.

## Use the Color Overlay Layer Style

To effectively change the color of such an image, using the **Color Overlay Layer Style** is best. Why? Because the color overlay will *completely* cover all pixels on a layer, including any hard to see *anti-aliased* pixels.

---

If you were to use the (yuck) Magic Wand Tool to click the clipboard pixels, then merely fill them with red, you *will* get a slight anti-alias border for the white. Which is what your screen shot is showing. **Often** these anti-alias pixels can be *really* hard to see against Photoshop's transparency grid. And the fact that they are white, increases the low visibility of such pixels. Just because you "don't see them" does *not* mean they aren't there. You have to zoom in, use different backgrounds, or other tricks to force them to be visible at times. Basically, *how* you changed the color has caused that "border".

There are other methods to change colors which are superior to the "magic wand/fill" method such as channel selections, or layer overlays, etc. But for general icons of a single flat color, the Color Overlay Layer Style is non-destructive and really a breeze to use.